# Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Closure given on Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to put together a query in Laravel Eloquent that will get a description then the rates associated with them but also group the rates by date and I think i'm close but I can't quite figure out what i'm doing wrong.

I get this error on the get() line with the below code;

> stripos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Closure
> given

```
$ratesbydate = RateDescription::where('company_id', '=', 7)->whereHas('rawrates', function ($query) use ($sub7days) {
     return $query->where('created_at', '>=', $sub7days)->orderByDesc('created_at')->groupBy(function($date) {
           return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('d'); 
     });
})->get();
```

If I remove the get and output ratesbydate I get the querybuilder. If I try changing the groupBy to just 'created_at' it runs ok but they aren't grouped by day then.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

-EDIT-
AS Iury Anadão suggested - I've tried adding the groupby after the get() - it wont be too data heavy. So I have this:

```
$ratesbydate = RateDescription::where('company_id', '=', 7)->whereHas('rawrates', function ($query) use ($sub7days) {
            return $query->where('created_at', '>=', $sub7days)->orderByDesc('created_at');
        })->get()->groupBy(function ($date) {
            return Carbon::parse($date->rawrates->created_at)->format('d'); 
        });
```

However I get this error:

> Property [created_at] does not exist on this collection instance.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot use closure in groupBy()

Comment: You can use a closure in the [`groupBy` method of the collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) but not of the query builder (which is what you are doing here). The collection `groupBy` also works differently than the SQL `GROUP BY` and here it's unclear which one you want to use. If you want to get multiple collections one for each day then swap `->get()` with `groupBy` so you get the result first before grouping the resulting collection

Comment: Think i've got myself confused tbh.

What I want is a collection of the rate descriptions, with the rates for each of those descriptions grouped by (and ordered by) date. So;

Description 1
 - 12th Oct 
  -£123
  -£124
 - 11th Oct
  -£111
Description 2
 - 12th Oct 
  -£113
  -£114
 - 11th Oct
  -£101
  -£100

Comment: what is the result you get when you ```dd``` the ```$date``` variable

Comment: I get the first ratedescription object

Answer (score 1):

You have some options to solve this.

You can use a groupByRaw, this way you can take the date from the database you are using and convert it with database functions.

```
$ratesbydate = RateDescription::where('company_id', '=', 7)
    ->whereHas('rawrates', function ($query) use ($sub7days) {
        return $query->where('created_at', '>=', $sub7days)
           ->orderByDesc('created_at')->groupByRaw("created_at::date");
    })->get();
```

In this example, I am using the database postgreSQL.

Example of groupByRaw in documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#groupbyraw

The other option to solve this is to use the group after the -> get(), this way you will be able to group the collection after bringing the information from the database, this is also a solution, but maybe it gets heavy if you are going to work a lot of data.

Example in documentation for groupby of collection:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby

Comment: Thanks. I've tried putting the groupby after the get() - I think i'm close but not quite there. I've updated the original post with my new code.